# React Native - NativeWind and react-native-dotenv conflict

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs, tailwind-css

I am new to React Native and am using Tailwind CSS and trying to implement react-native-dotenv.

I have installed NativeWind and Tailwind (as I believe you need both), which has been working up until I tried to implement react-native-dotenv.

The problem occurs when I update my `babel.config.js` to the following:

```js
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);

  const presets = ["babel-preset-expo"];
  const plugins = [
    "nativewind/babel",
    [
      "module:react-native-dotenv",
      {
        moduleName: "@env",
        path: ".env",
      },
    ],
  ];
  return { presets, plugins };
};
```

Within the plugins...

If I remove `nativewind/babel`, the project loads with expo and works as intended (with no styling).

If I remove `"module:react-native-dotenv...`, the project loads with expo and works as intended with styling but no Dotenv functionality.

When I include BOTH of the plugins together in the `babel.config.js` file, it shows this error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: nativewind__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.NativeWindStyleSheet is undefined
> js unitlessNumbers.js:76
> Webpack 48
> unitlessNumbers.js:76"

I've also tried to separate the plugins into different files and re-import them into `babel.config.js` with no luck.

I have used a `.babelrc` file along with `babel.config.js` with no luck either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to have similar problem, one of the possible solution is instead of using the `module:react-native-dotenv` plugin, you could try to use the `babel-plugin-module-resolver` package to resolve the path to the `.env` file, .

You can do this in your `babel.config.js` file:

```
return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    plugins: [
      "nativewind/babel",
      [
        "module-resolver",
        {
          alias: {
            "@env": "./.env",
          },
        },
      ],
    ],
  };
```

Good luck~

Comment: Most `.env` files are not JS/TS so the above would not work. babel will complain that it can't find the file